# mutiples conditions with if on a datraframe python, create function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with four columns.

[image: Dataframe]

I should have normally : `conso_HC=index_fin_HC-index_debut_HC`. But as you can see it's not the case, subtraction is really equal to that. The problem is that if we want to find conso_HC you need to add sometimes 100000 to one of the `index_fin_HC` or `index_debut_HC`.

```
 x=fichier['index_fin_HC']-fichier['index_debut_HC']
y=fichier['conso_HC']
def conditions(x,y):
    if x+100000==y:
        return x
    elif x==y+100000:
        return y
fichier['test']=fichirt
```

Comment: If I know what an addition is, you will never find conso_HC by adding 100000 to index_fin of index_debut. Where does this data come from?

Comment: actually, the problem is when you go to 100k, you restart at 0 sometimes, that's why you have to add 100k sometimes just to check if it's this problem or just an anomaly

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add an example of expected input and output.

Comment: I just want to replace directly the right value in the columns

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to build a new Series that test for the condition:

```
>>> (df.soustraction + 100000 == df.conso) | (df.soustraction - 100000 == df.conso)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool
```

You can then:

1. add it to the dataframe as a new column:

   ```
   df['condition'] = (df.soustraction + 100000 == df.conso) | (df.soustraction - 100000 == df.conso)
   ```
2. select rows in the dataframe matching the condition

   ```
   >>> df[(df.soustraction + 100000 == df.conso) | (df.soustraction - 100000 == df.conso)]
        debut     fin    conso  soustraction
   4  99193.0   526.0   1333.0      -98667.0
   5  91833.0  6407.0  14574.0      -85426.0
   ```
3. select rows in the dataframe not matching the condition

   ```
   >>> df[~ ((df.soustraction + 100000 == df.conso) | (df.soustraction - 100000 == df.conso))]
        debut     fin   conso  soustraction
   0  34390.0   414.0   452.0      -33976.0
   1  18117.0    85.0   216.0      -18032.0
   2  37588.0   234.0  8468.0      -37354.0
   3  49060.0    53.0  1399.0      -49007.0
   6  38398.0  1594.0  1994.0      -36804.0
   ```